# Let $R$ be a ring and $a ∈ R$. Let $S = \{r ∈ R : ra = 0\}$. Is $S$ necessarily a subring of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $R$ be a ring and $a ∈ R$. Let $S = \{r ∈ R : ra = 0\}$. Is $S$ necessarily a
> subring of $R$? Prove that it is, or find an explicit counterexample.

**My attempt:** Since $0a=0$, we have that $0\in S$. Let $r_1,r_2\in S$. Then $(r_1-r_2)a=r_1a-r_2a=0-0=0$. So $r_1-r_2$ lies in $S$. Finally, $r_1r_2a=r_10=0$. So $r_1r_2\in S$ and therefore $S$ is a subring of $R$. Is my proof correct? On the other hand, what is the interpretation of this exercise? I think it is that the set of zero divisors (which is not yet defined in the book) including $0$, form a subring. Am I right?

Comment: This comes down to your definition of "ring". Are you requiring your rings to have an identity element $1$? If not, then your proof seems good to me.

Comment: No, they do not require element $1$.

Comment: Your proof is correct if rings are not required to have a $1$. As to your final questions: (i) if $a\neq 0$, then this contains a subset of the left zero divisors of $R$ (they need not be two-sided zero divisors, and not every left zero divisor needs to be there). And (ii) if $a=0$, then you get all of $R$, which may include elements that are not even one-sided zero divisors.

Comment: The proof is correct, but the set of all zero divisors is not a subring in general: consider $\mathbb Z_{6}$: the set of zero divisors is $\{0,2,3\}$. which is not a subring.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *left ideal*, the [left annihiliator ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)) of $a$. With the [awkward definition](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/ring.pdf) of a ring not containing the unit element, left ideals are subrings; otherwise an ideal is a subring iff it is the whole ring, which means $a=0$ here.